# Let $K=\{ (1), (12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ and let $G=S_4$. Determine whether the following classes are disjoint or identical

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $K=\{ (1), (12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ and let $G=S_4$. $K$ is a subgroup of $S_4$.

Determine whether the following are disjoint or identical:

a) $K(12)$ and $K(34)$

b) $K(1234)$ and $K(1324)$

---

**for $a)$**

not fond of cyclic multiplication would rather due them in matrices but Ill try

For right coset ***$K(12)$***

$$\begin{aligned}
(1)*(12) &=(12) && {\text{ok}}
\\  (12)(34) *(12)&=(1)(2)(34) &&{\text{ok}}
 \\  (13)(24)* (12)&=(1423)  &&{\text{ok}}
  \\ (14)(23)*(12)&=(1324)  &&{\text{better now}}
\end{aligned} $$
For right coset ***$K(34)$***

$$\begin{aligned}
(1)*(34) &=(34) &&{\text{ok}}
\\  (12)(34) *(34)&=(12)(3)(4) &&{\text{ok}}
 \\  (13)(24)* (34)&=(1324)  &&{\text{ok}}
  \\ (14)(23)*(34)&=(1423)
\end{aligned} $$

*They look identical might have made a mistake since they don't completely match up*.

I need to verify that for $b$ it is disjoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe look at it more theorethically. We have $Kx = Ky \iff Kxy^{-1}=K \iff xy^{-1} \in K)$. So for a) we have $x = (1,2)$ and $y = y^{-1}=(3,4)$ so $xy^{-1}=(1,2)(3,4)$, but $(1,2)(3,4) \in K$, by definition of $K$, so the cosets are equal.
For b) we have $xy^{-1} = (1,2,3,4)(1,3,2,4)^{-1} =  (1,3,2) \notin K$, so the cosets are different.